# Yii: php -> Cannot execute SQL command in SiteController

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii, yii2

I have some problem when submitting the `_form.php` to `SiteController.php` this error message will appear,

"CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; "

It cannot run the query. Also try with another query command, the error is same.

SiteController.php

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Detail;
   if (isset($_POST['Detail'])) {
       // print_r($_POST['Detail']);
        $model->attributes = $_POST['Detail'];
        $connection = Yii::app()->db;

        $data = date('Y-m-d');
        $date = "'" . $data . "'";
        $teach_id = Yii::app()->user->getId();

        $i = 1;
        foreach ($_POST['Detail'] as $stud=>$status) 
        {
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO {{detail}} (`id`, `student_id`, `teacher_id`, `date`, `status`) VALUES 
                    (NULL, ' . $stud . ',' . $teach_id . ',' . $date . ', ' . $i . ' );';


            $command = $connection->createCommand($sql);
            $exec = $command->query();
        } 
        if ($exec) {
            $this->redirect(array('index'));
        }
    }
    $this->render('create', array('model' => $model, ));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace {{detail}} with real table name and use double quotes for whole string and single quote for each variable

```
"INSERT INTO {{detail}}
    (`id`, `student_id`, `teacher_id`, `date`, `status`)
VALUES
    (NULL, '$stud', '$teach_id', '$date', '$i');"
```

replace

```
$date = "'" . $data . "'";
```

to

```
$date = $data;
```

and you are using the same key of `$_POST` array in different cases

```
$model->attributes = $_POST['Detail'];
...
foreach ($_POST['Detail'] as $stud => $status)
```

Comment: actually `detail` is my real table name and i was change the code like you do, but the same error still appear

Comment: @mrdidie check out last version of answer

Comment: if i change `date = $data`, it cannot retreive the date value. What do you mean {same key of `$_POST` } ?

Comment: now i change sql statement like this:
`$sql = 'INSERT INTO `detail`(`id`,`student_id`,`teacher_id`,`date`,`status`) VALUES
                (NULL,'.$stud.','.$teach_id.','.$date.','.$i.');';`

and the error is `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'SH1004' in 'field list'. The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO `detail`(`id`,`student_id`,`teacher_id`,`date`,`status`) VALUES
(NULL,SH1004,CSH1001,'2015-07-02',1);`

Comment: @mrdidie use my example with double quotes "INSERT and ,'$date',

Comment: But, if i change to this statement, SQL can execute, while there is no values in student_id and teacher_id column:

``$sql = 'INSERT INTO `detail`(`id`,`student_id`,`teacher_id`,`date`,`status`) VALUES
                (NULL,student_id,teacher_id,'.$date.','.$i.');';``

Comment: @mrdidie SH1004 and SH1004 are strings you need to wrap them in quotes

Comment: @mrdidie Use my example

Comment: yeaaaayyyyyy ! its work ! thanks @alexandermadyuskin !

the problem is i not wrap the strings like you say 'SH1004'

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the  `'{{detail}}'` inside single quote. Single quote in PHP are managed `as is` and no evaluation of the content is performed. I think you  use curly braces to isolate the name of the variable you want evaluated and then the use of single quote is a mistake. 
For this you need or use double quote `" ......"` or use string concatenation like you do in other part of the SQL instruction..

Comment: put a `{{detail}}` in a single quote ?? and the whole SQL statement in double quote right ?, still not function and CDbException still appear. I dont know what is the correct syntax to execute this statement :(

Comment: NO!. The SQL statement in double quote and eventual literal in  single quote